# Formula works with manual input but not through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
A   B   C
1   10  145
1.1 11  0
1.2 12  0
1.3 13  0
2   14  145
2.1 15  0
2.2 16  0
3   17  145
3.1 18  0
3.2 19  0
```

Columns A and B in the table are my input data, column C is created with the following formula:

```
=IF(MOD([@A],1)=0,SUM([B]),0)
```

This is a simplified example and not the actual formula I am using, but it suffices as a minimal reproducible example.

When I enter this formula manually into the edit bar it works exactly as expected and produces the values in the table above. However, when I try to input this formula into the cells using VBA it fails. It gives me an error:

> Error: invalid name

If I then click the cell and into the edit bar as if I wanted to manipulate the formula manually and just immediately hit enter, without actually changing anything in the formula, the error vanishes and the results get correctly displayed once more as before.

The code I use to enter the formula into the cell via VBA is the following:

```
Sub InputFormula()
    Set srcTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    fmtString = "=IF(MOD([@A],1)=0,SUM([B]),0)"
    Range(srcTable.Name & "[C]").Formula = fmtString
End Sub
```

Why is the obviously correct formula broken when applied through VBA and how can I correct it so that application through VBA works?

I am using Excel 2019 on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce. I'm assuming that this dataset is a listobject/table?

Comment: Works as intended in Excel 2016.

Comment: Me neither, you've got different names for your Listobject columns ? i.e A B C, which will not work outside the ListObject

Comment: I edited the question to reflect that I am using Excel 2019. The dataset resides in a table. I tested with the exact same example provided above, values as well as column names.

Comment: Consider changing final line to `Range(srcTable.Name & "[C]").Formula = 0` -- to establish whether the argument being given to `Range` is the problem or the formula itself.

Comment: While trying to follow your suggestion @chillin, I suddenly was not able to reproduce the example anymore. I didn't save the document so I copied everything from my post above and it worked. Then I realized what the difference was: I am using a localized version of Excel. I translated the function names into English for posting them here. When I put together the example earlier I used the function names in my language and then it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution to my problem:

I am using a non-English version of Excel. When I try to use the localized function names in VBA it comes up with an error as described in the question. When I use the corresponding English names though, everything works as expected.

This is counterintuitive, because when I apply conditional formatting through VBA I have to use the localized function names. Using the English ones there does not work.

Comment: You chose a bad example because your sample formula is a valid `en-us` formula, and as you said that it was accepted by the interface, I assumed you used `en-us` Excel. Yes, `.Formula` accepts only `en-us` formulas, and `.FormulaLocal` accepts the localized formulas. You don't have that choice for `.FormulaArray` that only works with `en-us` and, as you have discovered, for conditional formatting that only works with localized formulas.

Comment: I wanted to make the example reproducible for everybody, that's why I translated the names to English so everybody could understand them. Had I known that exactly this was the problem, I obviously wouldn't have done that :) At least it helped me to figure out what I was doing wrong.